# Library index error in ROS Foxy

Tags: ros, cmake, build, library, errors

The error is shown below:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/connext_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindConnext.cmake:165 (list):
  list index: libnddsc.so is not a valid index
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/connext_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindConnext.cmake:200 (_count_found_libraries)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c-extras.cmake:5 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_connext_cConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_typesupport_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_c-extras.cmake:13 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_typesupport_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_cConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_default_runtime/cmake/rosidl_default_runtime-extras.cmake:12 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_default_runtime/cmake/rosidl_default_runtimeConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/builtin_interfaces/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/builtin_interfaces/cmake/builtin_interfacesConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rcl_interfaces/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rcl_interfaces/cmake/rcl_interfacesConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rcl/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rcl/cmake/rclConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/libstatistics_collector/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/libstatistics_collector/cmake/libstatistics_collectorConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rclcpp/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rclcpp/cmake/rclcppConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  app/startapplication_cm_client1/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

Below is the environment info

- ROS: Foxy
- Ubuntu: 20.04
- cmake: 3.25.1

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Please edit you question to provide enough context to reproduce your problem. A minimal self contained example is best, but at least enough to reproduce your workspace and all the commands and environment you have configured. The traceback provides pointers to that context which is unknown to readers here.